# Mods and ASCII in VB Caesar Shift

Tags: vb.net, ascii, modulo

I have this code which shifts the alphabet by a certain amount. The size of the alphabet is 26. When I enter a larger size shift (for example 22) I get some weird characters displaying. I think I need to mod the ASCII alphabet to 26 to get it working but Im not quite sure which bit to mod.

Basically I need to wrap around the alphabet (once it reaches Z it goes back to letter A) Do I have to create a dictionary for the mod to work (like A = 0... Z = 26) or can I stick with using the normal ASCII table? Here is the code below:

```
Public Function encrypt(ByVal input As String) 'input is a variable within the funcion
    Dim n as Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    n = key.Text Mod 26 'gets what is in the text box of 'key' and sets it as n
    ' the key is a multiple of 26 so 26 will  = 0

    'need to remove white spaces
    While input.Contains(" ")           'when the input text contains a space
        input = input.Replace(" ", "")  'replaces it with no space.
    End While


    For i = 1 To Len(input)                                     'find the length of the input
        Mid(input, i, 1) = Chr(Asc(Mid(input, i, 1)) + n)       'chr returns the character associated with the specified character code
        '
    Next
    encrypt = input
End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this code:

```
For i = 1 To Len(input)                                     'find the length of the input
    Mid(input, i, 1) = Chr(Asc(Mid(input, i, 1)) + n)       'chr returns the character associated with the specified character code
    '
Next
```

String indexes are **0-based**.  Your first index is 0, not 1!  Also, you are assigning to the result of a function call. You need to instead construct a new string.

You didn't say, but the way you used the Replace and Contains methods indicates .Net, and if that's the case, I would do it like this:

```
Public Function encrypt(ByVal key As Integer, ByVal input As String) As String 'Don't forget the return type on the function
    key = key Mod 26
    Return New String(input.Replace(" ", "").ToUpper().Select(Function(c) Chr(((Asc(c) + key - Asc("A"c)) Mod 26) + Asc("A"c))).ToArray())
End Function
```

Just like that, and it's almost a one-liner. I can see this works now by calling it this way:

```
Encrypt("C"c, "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog")
Encrypt("D"c, "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog")
```

The results:

```
BPMYCQKSJZWEVNWFRCUXMLWDMZBPMTIHGLWOA
CQNZDRLTKAXFWOXGSDVYNMXENACQNUJIHMXPB
```

Look for the results mapped for the word "lazy", and you will see that the 'a' wraps to 'z' and 'y' correctly, and that the 'D' key results are one letter off of the 'C' results.

Comment: Regarding your comment about zero-based indices, `Mid` uses a 1-based index, so the loop was fine, anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Sorry about the stupid questions, I am still quite new to this language. I am not quite sure what the code does and how it works and i got very confused. I have tried replacing my code with yours and it doesn't seem to convert anything. How could I get it to wrap around (for example letter Z with shift 3 would go back to letter C)?

Comment: @K_McCormic I had a typo: an = character instead of a plus (bad shift key). I also don't have a compiler handy, so it's still untested, but should be at least a little closer now.

Comment: I am still very confused :( All i see is blue lines and I am not quite sure what anything does. Sorry for wasting your time :(

Comment: Try it now: just needed to fix a parentheses... easy enough now that I'm at a machine with visual studio to help me spot it.

Comment: Oh ok i think I understand it a bit better now. If I was to replace the key with a number say 3 instead of C, do I just set it as an integer?

Comment: Yes, that would be okay. I used a "Char" type for the key because that matched your original code.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. This may seem like a very stupid question... But which bit do you replace to get it to have a numeric key instead of a letter? (say 3 instead of C) Thanks for all the help again

Comment: Edited the answer to use an integer key

Comment: When the key 3 is entered it seems to shift the whole alphabet 15 places instead of 3. ps. you have been credited in the code :)

Comment: One more round then. Force the string to upper case and subtract the value of "A" before "wrapping" the text around.